# SAMBA: Why do symbolic links work on Windows but not cifs mount on Ubuntu?

Tags: mount, samba

A SAMBA server has a **symbolic link**, which I can verify it by mounting the same server with NFS:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root     25 Aug 14 20:07 folder -> ../../../../folder/
```

The problem is, Windows can successfully recognize the symbolic link and access the linked folder, but on Ubuntu it fails because the symbolic link is treated like a common file:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   0 Aug 14 20:07 folder*
```

What I used for the `mount` command was:

```
mount -t cifs //server/shared-folder local-folder -o username=tom,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,nounix
```

[image: schema]

I have checked several solutions on SE, but all of them (e.g. [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147285/260981)) require a modification of the `smb.conf` file, which I don't have the permission.

So, my question is, since the Windows can access the symbolic link, is there any solution for the SAMBA client on Ubuntu to do this, without touching anything on the SAMBA server?

Answer (score 1):

Your symbolic link points to a folder outside of the shared directory. Therefore it is not accessible in the mounted file system on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I didn't express it clearly, the link target is not a local folder of the Windows system either. See my update :)

Comment: Still your picture shows that the link target is _outside_ the shared folder, so it cannot be reached in the samba mount. I don't know why this works in windows - is there a second share?

Comment: Your picture does not correspond to the link you gave. `../../../../folder` should be a subdirectory of shared-folder.

Comment: Yes, the link target is indeed **outside** the shared folder. I confirmed there was no other share by `net use * /del` and then immediately accessed the `\\server\shared-folder` on a windows machine. It's really amazing that this works in windows. Theoretically speaking, if windows can do it, ubuntu should be able too.

Comment: Perhaps windows has a folder of the same name above the mount point. You cannot access something on the remote server which is outside the shared folder. If you could, you would have access to all files on the server by creating a symbolic link with a relative path pointing there.

Comment: The symbolic link was created in an NFS mount (not CIFS mount) by the administrator of the server. The target folder is indeed only on the server (the content clearly proves it).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81747/discussion-between-stan-and-muclux).